Reentrancy Vulnerability
I've noticed that the offer function uses the .call{value: amount}("") method to send Ether to the recipient's address.
Could anyone provide insight into whether this function is indeed vulnerable to reentrancy and suggest any best practices or modifications to mitigate such risks?
function _offer(address to, uint256 amount) internal {
      
      balance -= amount;

      (bool success, ) = to.call{value: amount}("");
      if (!success) {
          revert TransferFailed(address(0), address(this), to, amount);
      }
  }


It shouldn't be affected by a reentrancy because the effects are applied before making the call
balance -= amount;

(bool success, ) = to.call{value: amount}("");

I'm assuming the rest of the contract is secure, and solc version generate a revert when balance < amount.

thank you for your help
